# How to show an OAuth dialog for a Facebook application accessed via a fan page tab?

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebook-page

I'm developing a Facebook application as a Page Tab App. I want to show the [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) dialog box before the user access the application via the fan page. How can I do this?

For a canvas app, when I enable the OAuth dialog box from the application settings (Enhanced Auth Dialog) the OAuth dialog box is shown when the application is accessed via `apps.facebook.com/myapp`.But when I access the same application using the page tab added inside a fan page, the OAuth dialog is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

See the tutorial *[Canvas Tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/#auth)*.

The key trick is that you need to target the "_top" window (outside of the iframe)... For example,

```
echo('<script> top.location.href="' . $auth_url . '"</script>');
```

or

```
echo('<a target="_top" href="' . $auth_url . '">Authorize this application...</a>');
```

To my knowledge you can not complete this authorization flow inside of the iframe.

I also recommend watching the short video *[Authentication: An Overview](http://developers.facebook.com/videos/#authentication)* from Facebook Developer Garage: Paris (2011-03-29).

If you want to request authentication (or add on some additional permissions after authentication) see the two JavaScript SDK functions, [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) and [FB.login](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/). Take note that `FB.login` launches a popup window - so it must be triggered from a user `click` event (or some browsers will block the popup). The benefit of this method is it doesn't require page redirects - the popup communicates back the response without a reload.